# Files gone after update Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS

Tags: updates, files

I use Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS. Today there was an update. after the update all my accounts were deconnected, Thunderbirds connection to my email adresses was gone, all files deleted. A lot of files (however not all) from home directory (Pictures, documents etc) was gone. Not in the thrash and i didnt find them. There is no partitioned harddisk, i run the computer only with ubuntu.
So I am pretty new to ubuntu and use it since a year. I am devastated.
My bad for not taking care for backup.
Any Ideas what happened? I dont know what to do. Thanks for advice. please tell me if you need more information to evaluate the situation better.

Comment: I'm going to guess that something has moved stuff around in an unexpected way. Think hard about the exact name of a file that you know you had before update and that isn't where you expect it now. Try a find from root: `sudo find / -name 'myfile*'`

Comment: "*Any Ideas what happened?*" No need to guess. Pull the logs and see. Updates are recorded at `/var/log/apt/history.log` and `/var/log/apt/term.log`